# How to increment a value by X

Tags: java, calculator, increment, var

I'm trying to find a java code to my calculation below,

can't find how to increment the value by 53 and 79 ,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int weight, b;

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the Weight : ");
    weight = (int) sc.nextDouble();
    b = calculateLandingRate(weight);

    System.out.println("Total price  : " + b);
}
static int calculateLandingRate(int weight) {

    int rate = 26;

    if (weight<= 25) {
        if (weight > 1) {
            int totalPrice = 26 * weight;
        } else if (weight> 25 && weight < 75) ;`
```

---

total price= (the weight 26kg ) + 53 ,
 the calculation should be like the value is incremented by 53 ,from the weight =26kg

```
       /* int rate = +53;
        Total price at 26kg = 650 + 53 =703
        Total price at 27kg = 703 + 53=756
        Total price at 28kg = 756 + 53 =809
        Total price at 29kg = 809 + 53 =862
        Total price at 30kg = 862 + 53 =915

        *
        *
        *

        Total price at 75kg = 3247 + 53 =3300
   */
} 

else if (weight > 75) ;
```

the value increment by 79

int rate = +79;

```
Total price at 76kg = 3300 + 79 =3379
*
*
*
*

Total price at 624 kg = 46592 + 79 =46671
```

Comment: It's `+=`, not `=+`. `int rate = +79` just sets the value of `rate` to 79. `int rate += 79` is basically shorthand for `int rate = rate + 79`

Comment: thanks ,the problem is , in the input for example 70 , the value should be like
rate =(the value of rate of input -1)+79  ,

Comment: if the user input weight >26 && weight<=75 ,the totalPrice is incremented by 53 starting from weight=26kg ,that equals 703, the next weight 27kg  will be 703+53=756 ,the next weight 28kg will be 756+53 =809 ....and so on

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are after is this

```
  static int calculateLandingRate(int weight) {

    int lowRate = 26;
    int midRate = 53;
    int highRate = 79;

    int lowRateLimit = 25;
    int midRateLimit = 75;

    int totalPrice = 0;
    if (weight > 1 && weight <= lowRateLimit) {
      totalPrice = lowRate * weight;
    } else if (weight > lowRateLimit && weight <= midRateLimit) {
      totalPrice = lowRate * lowRateLimit + midRate * (weight - lowRateLimit);
    } else if (weight > midRateLimit) {
      totalPrice = lowRate * lowRateLimit + midRate * (midRateLimit - lowRateLimit) + highRate * (weight - midRateLimit);
    }

    return totalPrice;

  }
```

Remarks:

- Your elseif statement `else if (weight> 25 && weight < 75)` is always false
- you define `rate` but do not use it

Answer (score 1):

Do it as follows:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int weight, b;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the weight : ");
        weight = sc.nextInt();
        b = calculateLandingRate(weight);
        System.out.println("Total price  : " + b);
    }

    static int calculateLandingRate(int weight) {
        final int RATE = 26;
        final int LOWERLIMIT = 25;
        final int LOWERLIMITADDER = 53;
        final int UPPERLIMIT = 75;
        final int UPPERLIMITADDER = 79;

        // Base price
        int price = LOWERLIMIT * RATE;

        if (weight > 25 && weight <= 75) {
            price += LOWERLIMITADDER * (weight - LOWERLIMIT);
        } else if (weight > 75) {
            price += LOWERLIMITADDER * (UPPERLIMIT - LOWERLIMIT);
            price += UPPERLIMITADDER * (weight - UPPERLIMIT);
        }
        return price;
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Enter the weight : 24
Total price  : 650
```

**Another sample run:**

```
Enter the weight : 25
Total price  : 650
```

**Another sample run:**

```
Enter the weight : 40
Total price  : 1445
```

**Another sample run:**

```
Enter the weight : 74
Total price  : 3247
```

**Another sample run:**

```
Enter the weight : 75
Total price  : 3300
```

**Another sample run:**

```
Enter the weight : 80
Total price  : 3695
```

**Another sample run:**

```
Enter the weight : 624
Total price  : 46671
```

Comment: Thanks Arvinds,
but the output is not what is expected ,
The value weight is a user input value from 1 till 624,when the user enter ofr example the weight 20 kg ,the equation totalPrice= 20*26 
if the 1<weight<25 the totalPrice = the input weight * 26 .
if the 26<weight<75 the totalprice is incremented by 53 starting from the totalPrice value of 25Kg = 25*26=650 
so the totalPrice at 26 KG =650+53 =703
   the totalPrice at 27 KG =703+53  and so on till the the Weight value of 76 when the incremented value will changed to 79 ;

Comment: the Total price at 75kg = 3247 + 53 =3300
   the Total price at 76kg = 3300 + 79 =3379**
and so on .

Comment: That's correct. My test results also show the same result. Do you see any discrepancy? Instead of writing `3300` in the formula, I've used the variables so that you do not need to change much when the values change in the future.

Comment: Output

Please enter the Weight :40

Weight = 24, Price = 650
Weight = 25, Price = 650
Weight = 26, Price = 703
Weight = 27, Price = 756
Weight = 28, Price = 809
Weight = 74, Price = 3247
Weight = 75, Price = 3300
Weight = 76, Price = 3379
Weight = 77, Price = 3458
Weight = 78, Price = 3537
Weight = 624, Price = 46671

there is no value of 40

Comment: I still didn't understand what problem you are facing.